# Failing to install Gradle IDE Pack 3.8.x+1.0.x on Eclipse 2020-06

Tags: eclipse, gradle, eclipse-plugin, ide, gradle-plugin

whenever I try to install the Gradle IDE Pack 3.8.x+1.0.x+2.2.x on my Eclipse I get following error message:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: a.jre.javase 16.0.0
  Software currently installed: BOSH Language Server Feature 4.9.0.202012131915 (org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls.feature.feature.group 4.9.0.202012131915)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Language Server Protocol client for Eclipse IDE (Incubation) 0.13.4.202011121435 (org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.13.4.202011121435)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: BOSH Language Server Feature 4.9.0.202012131915 (org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls.feature.feature.group 4.9.0.202012131915)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.lsp4e 0.0.0
```

I use Eclipse 2020-06 and Java 8. From what I understand I would need minimum Java 11.

Is there a way to overgo that without using Java 11? We have to stick to Java 8 for now.

Thanks for support.

Comment: You can still develop Java 8 programs (or any other version) with Eclipse 2020-12, it just needs Java 11 for itself

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to JDK11 didn't solve the issue (alone at least). The BOSCH Language Server from the Spring Tool Plus-In must be uninstalled as well.